# How to use commas to improve clarity?

Tags: commas

> The same condition may be described, in English, in different ways –
> and hence be checked by different, but equivalent, Boolean blocks.
>
> Source: The Open University

I think I can write the quote as "The same condition may be described **in English in different ways** - and hence be checked by **different but equivalent** Boolean blocks. It is grammatical, but the quote is clearer. I want to know some guidance about using commas like the way in the quote.

Comment: Correction of your suggestion: different **ways**, hence be **checked**. This is not an answer.

Comment: I think the commas make it clearer.

Comment: Commas can be used as a pause effect like the one people do when speaking. However, it is not nominally good to use commas a lot with this aim.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the commas in the original versuion of the text are not only acceptable, they are **mandatory**, and the version without them is at least technically incorrect.

Some people say that commas just indicate where a speaker would pause. I say that is wring. Commas have grammatical and syntactic functions. For example, to separate list items, to separate certain clauses, and to set off parenthetical information. Pauses in speech are to indicate where the commas would be in writing, not the other way around. pauses in speech depend o the speakers voice, far more so than commas in writing depend on style.

in the original example " in English" and "but equivalent" are additional helpfule pievces ofd information, not essential to the meaning of the sentence. Thus they should be set off by commas. The [answer by George K]( [https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/316967/91457]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/316967/91457%5D) does a good job of explaining the function of each section of the example test, I will not repeat that analysis.  The commas should not be omitted here, although most fluent speakers will correctly understand it if they are, albeit with more effort.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>*Note: Your suggestion reads "The same condition may be described in English in different **way** - and hence be **check** by different but equivalent Boolean blocks." As it is written it is ungramatical. This answer is assuming you meant "different **ways**" and "be **checked**."*</strike>

To my ear, the original punctuation is clearer than the alternative you suggest. Though there are formal rules and guidelines about punctuation use in writing, the first quote's punctuation **closely mirrors the way the quote would be read aloud**. Using commas to indicate short pauses, I would read the quote aloud as follows:

> The same condition may be described**,** in English**,**in different ways**,** and hence be checked by different**,** but equivalent**,** Boolean blocks.

Given the complexity of the sentence, another obstacle for a reader is parsing the *basic structure* of the sentence. In this case, we can reduce the sentence to something like:

> X may be described in different ways – and hence be checked by different Y.

Treating the phrases "in english" and "but equivalent" as non-essential (putting commas around them) **lets the reader skip the work** of deciding whether they are *structurally important*. In the alternative you propose, the reader has to keep a lot more in their head. For example, reading from the start of the sentence:

> The same condition (*noun phrase, no trouble*) 
> may be described (*verb phrase; either intransitive or transitive, so possibly expecting an object to follow*) 
> in English (*adverbial phrase; deduction: this must either apply to the preceding verb phrase or something else; waiting to see*) 
> in different ways (*another adverbial phrase; same deduction, same waiting*) 
> -- (*punctuation now resolves attribution of two adverbial phrases: they apply to the verb*)

If we instead put commas around *in English*, we save the reader the work of waiting to attribute the phrase.

In summary, the original punctuation is more natural easier to parse.

Comment: I agree with you, though, your answer looks more about what effect the commas give. I'm asking the guidance about the way using commas in the quote. Like, how to use commas improve clarity or read experience. General rules, I can use in my own writing, with some examples are better.

Comment: I see. I've tried to explain what the author is doing that makes his or her use of commas helpful. Unfortunately, other than "make sure you're using them correctly" (e.g. appropriately when joining clauses, not misusing semicolons or dashes, etc.), any more specific advice will fall under *style*. Each author has his own style, and I'm sure yours is unique as well. Maybe a different answerer can give general recommendations for how to use commas to improve readability.